# Google Chrome: Something went wrong while displaying webpage, can't even access settings

Tags: google-chrome

I powered on my laptop today, launched Chrome, and got the error: `Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.` I thought, "no big deal," I will just refresh; didn't work. I tried restarting my laptop (4 times); didn't work. I tried clearing the cache, but couldn't even access the settings page to do so, due to the error. I am really at a loss for how to resolve this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it for a specific page/server or for all pages? Did you check your network connectivity?

Comment: Did you try 1/ Reinstalling Chrome? 2/ Using a new user profile?